# How to display images of a post in random order - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, function, post

I have a page in my wordpress, in which I have added three images via the "add media" button.

Now, I am looking for a way to **display these images one at a time and in a random order**.

Just guessing that I would have to call `the_content` of the page and write some PHP to display the images one at a time in random order? But since I don't know how to write such a function, some help would be huge!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find many plugins for this.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/random-image/

OR

if you use custom post type then this might be help full to you.

Use array_unique() before foreach:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $images = get_field('gallery');

    // thumbnail
    if( $images ): 
?>
    <ul id="container" class="tiles-wrap animated">
        <?php 
            $images = array_rand($images); 
            $images = array_unique($images);

            foreach( $images as $image ): 

                // $rand_class = array('small', 'medium', 'large');
                $size = 'medium';
                $thumb = $image['sizes'][ $size ];
                $width = $image['sizes'][ $size . '-width' ];
                $height = $image['sizes'][ $size . '-height' ]; ?>

               <li><img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['medium']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" width="<?php echo $width; ?>" height="<?php echo $height; ?>" /></li>       

            <?php endforeach;
       endif; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: I would rather like not to use any plugins. Usually, plugins ask to use shortcode and my client can't do that, it has to be easily settable for him. Is custom post type a plugin? How can I use the code you have written? (It ends with a fatal error on my page)

Comment: you can use this in your project Functions file or if you use child theme then create functions.php file and use this

Comment: Ok, but I need just one page to have the random function. If I use it in my functions.php file, every pages of my site will get the function.

Comment: if( !is_page(your page id) )
    return; @Lolo

OR

http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages look under Creating Your Own Page Templates